# Blocked loading mixed active content in reactjs app after deploying in github pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages, fetch-api

I am building a simple movie search app using reactjs and **omdbapi** api the app works fine in local host, but after deploying in github pages i get this error

Blocked loading mixed active content “http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=l&apikey=ca6be1d4”
App.js:19:28
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

Comment: use https instead of http for omdbapi. eg. https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=l&apikey=ca6be1d4

Comment: Serve backend over https. It’s blocking because GitHub pages serves content over https and it is making call to http endpoints